# Date class conversion

Tags: javascript

I have next code to take date:

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.toString();
```

with output: Sun Oct 15 2017 12:09:42 GMT+0300 (EEST)
But I need to convert it to next format: `2017-10-15 12:09:42 +0300`
Is that possible to do with Date class methods or I should use some regex for output string, to format it?

Comment: MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done easily with a library called [`moment.js`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/), please go through the docs for any additional tweaks, please check my below example and let me know if this helps you!

```js
var moment_d = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss ZZ');
console.log(moment_d);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please don't just add this dependency just to format a date, especially on the client-side.

Comment: Sure it will, but it's also completely overkill for his requirements, at the cost of substantial browser performance.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in JavaScript's Date object that will conveniently get you the desired output. On the other hand, moment.js is a 80+ KB beast which is clearly an overkill in most situations.

There are some lightweight solutions out there if you look for them.

Alternatively you could parse the output of `.toISOString()`, which gets you as far as `'2017-10-15T12:09:42.301Z'`, and combine it with `.getTimezoneOffset()` which returns the number of minutes from the UTC (positive towards West).

JS date-time manipulation libraries being large as they are, I recommend rolling your own if you only need to cover a few cases.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function formatDate(date) {
    date = date || new Date(); // default to current time if parameter is not supplied
    let formattedDate = date.toISOString(); // returns 2000-01-04T00:00:00.000Z
    const timezone = date.getTimezoneOffset() / 0.6; // returns timezone in minutes, so dividing by 0.6 gives us e.g -100 for -1hr
    const timezoneString = String(timezone) // padStart is a method on String
                          .padStart(4, '0') // add zeroes to the beginning if only 1 digits
                          .replace(/^(-|\+)(\d{3})$/, '$10$2') // add a zero between a - or + and the first digit if needed
                          .replace(/^\d/, '+$&'); // add a plus to the beginning if zero timezone difference

    formattedDate = formattedDate
                    .replace('T', ' ') // replace the T with a space
                    .replace(/\.\d{3}Z/, '') // remove the Z and milliseconds
                    + ' ' // add a space between timezone and time
                    + timezoneString; // append timezone
                    

    return formattedDate;
}

console.log(formatDate(new Date(2016, 08, 24, 9, 20, 0)));
console.log(formatDate(new Date(2015, 03, 9, 18, 4, 30)));
console.log(formatDate(new Date(1999, 12, 4)));
console.log(formatDate(new Date(1999, 01, 4)));
console.log('----');
```